# Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, bignumber

I can not find what the problem is, someone can help me

Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.9;

contract certificarProceso {

    address public creador;
    address emisor;
    string informacion;
    string informacionHashArchivo;

    function escribirInformacion(string memory informacion1, string memory informacionHashArchivo1) public {
        informacion = informacion1;
        informacionHashArchivo = informacionHashArchivo1;
    }

    function getInformacion() public view returns (string memory) {
        return informacion;
    }

    function getInformacionArchivoHash() public view returns (string memory) {
        return informacionHashArchivo;
    }
}
```

Error

```
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
Unlock account 0x2fef34e4d5a83a7bd78b2b09eb3619046eb1eaa1
Passphrase: 
true
> var abi= [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"informacion1","type":"string"},{"name":"informacionHashArchivo1","type":"string"}],"name":"escribirInformacion","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"creador","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInformacion","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInformacionArchivoHash","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
undefined
> 
> var address ="0x93ba4ede5903c6656060c443255ed4ef569a5144"
undefined
> var contract=eth.contract(abi).at(address)
undefined
> contract.getInformacion()
Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: 
    at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)
    at bignumber.js:3:8435
    at a (bignumber.js:3:389)
    at web3.js:1110:23
    at web3.js:1634:20
    at web3.js:826:16
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:825:12
    at web3.js:4080:18

>
```

Comment: Are you pointing the right contract address? Do you have synched your blockchain?

Comment: Hello Alberto, if my blockchain is synchronized and that is the correct address of the contract.

I do not know where to look

Comment: Have you deployed the contract? How did you get this address: `0x93ba4ede5903c6656060c443255ed4ef569a5144`?

Comment: when I made the deploy I returned that contract address

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the contract's address is undefined.

in the console remove the keyword var in the instantiation and keep just :

```
address ="0x93ba4ede5903c6656060c443255ed4ef569a5144"
```

same for abi ...

you can check afterwards if the value set by just typing the variable name in the console

exp

```
> address

0x93ba4ede5903c6656060c443255ed4ef569a5144
```